# How to play a lot wav files in chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, audio

I have a problem with playing .wav in chrome. I store .wav files on aws s3, but than I trying play it, I get audio error "MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED".

I use [beaqlejs](https://github.com/HSU-ANT/beaqlejs) to play audio.
The most interesting thing is that in Firefox everything works well. May be the problem in that I get audio from s3, but I just assume it.

What can you suggest me?